# hotplug script in Tomato Shibby

Tags: usb, symbolic-link, tomato

I use Advanced Tomato on my Asus RT-AC68R/U. This is Shibby  Tomato with some GUI modification only. I want to connect via USB measuring unit and create for it dedicated, unique device. At this moment, Tomato creates device named /dev/usbdevX.Y where X and Y are random numbers. Below is part of my hotplug script. It is not final version, just part of my investigation to resolve the problem.

```
PRODID="5555/1/600"
SYMLINK="arco"

if [ "${PRODUCT}" = "${PRODID}" ];
then if [ "${ACTION}" = "add" ];
then
DEVICE_NAME=$(ls /sys/$DEVPATH)
echo $DEVICE_NAME > /tmp/arco1
echo $DEVPATH > /tmp/arco2
if [ -z ${DEVICE_NAME} ];
then echo " Hotplug Warning DEVICE_NAME is empty" > /tmp/arco
exit
fi
```

The variable DEVPATH returns value:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
```

Variable DEVICE_NAME returns listing of content of /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0 directory.

lsusb returns for that device value:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 5555:0001
```

The subdir /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0 consist files:

```
root@asus:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0# ls
bAlternateSetting     bInterfaceProtocol    bus                          interface             supports_autosuspend
bInterfaceClass       bInterfaceSubClass    ep_02                 modalias              uevent
bInterfaceNumber      bNumEndpoints         ep_81                 subsystem
```

And the file uevent consist:

```
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PHYSDEVBUS=usb
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/003/007
PRODUCT=5555/1/600
TYPE=0/0/0
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v5555p0001d0600dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFF
```

Notice that the line:

```
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/003/007
```

corresponds to lsusb output for that device. So it is for sure my new connected device

My question is. How in this case I can create symbolic link for such random created device to /dev/arco?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out solution. This is my working hotplug script. It creates symlink of /dev/arco to new created "generic" device named /dev/usbdev3.Y where Y is a random numbers. I use Advanced Tomato, so the script is added in section NAS&USB -> USB Support -> Hotplug script

```
PRODID="5555/1/600"
SYMLINK="arco"

if [ "${PRODUCT}" = "${PRODID}" ];
then if [ "${ACTION}" = "add" ];
then
echo $DEVICE > /tmp/arco1


if [ -z ${DEVICE} ];
then echo " Hotplug Warning DEVICE is empty" > /tmp/arco
exit
fi

usb=`echo -n $DEVICE | tail -c 1`
echo " Hotplug Device name of ARCO is $DEVICE" > /tmp/arco
ln -s /dev/usbdev3.$usb /dev/${SYMLINK}
echo " Hotplug Symlink from $DEVICE to /dev/${SYMLINK} created" > /tmp/arco
fi
fi

if [ "${PRODUCT}" = "${PRODID}" ];
then if [ "${ACTION}" = "remove" ];
then rm /dev/${SYMLINK}
echo " Hotplug Symlink /dev/${SYMLINK} removed" > /tmp/arco
fi
fi
```

And thats all ;-)